# Multiple filter inside VueJS Computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs2, vue-component

This code is not working, when i try to add another filter inside computed it does't work, if i remove it, the code works fine.

I am trying to have companies and product searches on a single page, the companies filter works fine if the products filter is removed.

```js
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
            return {
            info: [],
            products: [],
            search: '',
            prosearch: ''
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
            .get(`${URL}/api/`)
            .then(response => (this.info = response.data))

             axios
            .get(`${URL}/api/`)
            .then(response => (this.products = response.data))
        },
        computed:{
            filterdata: function(){
                return this.info.filter((info)=>{
                    return info.name.match(this.search)
                });
            },
            Anotherfilterdata: function(){
                return this.products.filter((product)=>{
                    return product.name.match(this.prosearch)
                });
            },
        }
})
```

Comment: you're calling the  same endpoint twice

Comment: No, i removed the endpoints. Both are different

Comment: does the product filter work? when the company filter "doesn't work", is there any indication in the browser developer tools as to what the issue may be? and what does "doesn't work" mean? everything filtered? nothing filtered?

Comment: @Bravo No. the filter does't work. When both filters are added none works if the products filter is removed then the company filter works.  When both filters are added it shows " ReferenceError: products is not defined."

Comment: can you show the template, where it's using `filterdata` and `Anotherfilterdata` - because I just dummied up your code with a simple template and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code with mock data and it's working completely fine. It means that there is no issue with your computed properties but with fetching the data from APIs.

Check this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-computed-properties-x7vgk?file=/src/App.vue)

Since you didn't add any errors, let me break down the situation.
You are fetching the data from APIs in mounted, at this moment markup has been rendered but you do not have the data in product and info arrays because Axios has not resolved the promises yet. For this reason, when you are trying to use Anotherfilterdata or filterdata or both, one of them at that moment doesn't have the data hence breaking the code.

I would suggest that you check your console, there must be some errors related to what I described above.